# Why MySql query is taking time to return the result?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, HEADER and LINES tables. HEADER table has 5464 rows and the LINES table has 545335 rows. The query is taking around 1 minute to return the result. Is it because of the number of rows or any other factor like server config that affects query performance?

Table structures are given below:

```
CREATE TABLE `HEADER` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CUSTOMER` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CUSTOMER_ADDRESS` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VENDOR` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PROCESSING_STATUS` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `INDX_CUSTOMER` (`CUSTOMER`),
  KEY `INDX_VENDOR` (`VENDOR`),
  KEY `INDX_PROCESS_STATUS` (`PROCESSING_STATUS`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8090 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci


CREATE TABLE `LINES` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `HEADER_ID` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `FILE_NO` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LINE_NAME` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LINE_DESCRIPTION` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `INDX_HD_ID` (`HEADER_ID`)
  KEY `INDX_FL_NO` (`INVOICE_NO`),
  KEY `INDX_STATUS` (`STATUS`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=900063 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

My query is:

```
SELECT H_PREVIOUS.*, L.*, CONCAT(L.FILE_NO, H_PREVIOUS.CUSTOMER, H_PREVIOUS.VENDOR) AS UNIQUE_COL
FROM HEADER H_PREVIOUS
JOIN HEADER H_LATEST ON H_LATEST.CUSTOMER = H_PREVIOUS.CUSTOMER AND H_LATEST.VENDOR = H_PREVIOUS.VENDOR AND H_LATEST.PROCESSING_STATUS = 1 AND H_PREVIOUS.PROCESSING_STATUS = 1 AND H_LATEST.ID > H_PREVIOUS.ID
JOIN LINES L ON L.HEADER_ID_ID = H_PREVIOUS.ID AND L.STATUS <> 'P'
LEFT JOIN LINES L_LATEST ON L_LATEST.HEADER_ID = H_LATEST.ID AND L_LATEST.FILE_NO = L.FILE_NO
WHERE L_LATEST.FILE_NO IS NULL
GROUP BY UNIQUE_COL;
```

The output of the query will give you the lines which are present in header 1 and not present in header 2 with status F.

E.g.

```
HEADER:
-------
1   100   ASDF   1000   1
2   100   ASDF   1000   1

LINES
------
1   1   F1   FFF   DDDD   P
2   1   F2   FFF   DDDD   F
3   1   F3   FFF   DDDD   F
4   1   F4   FFF   DDDD   F
5   2   F2   FFF   DDDD   F
6   2   F4   FFF   DDDD   F

Output:
--------
1   100   ASDF   1000   1   2   1   F2   FFF   DDDD   F   F21001000
1   100   ASDF   1000   1   3   1   F4   FFF   DDDD   F   F41001000
```

Output of Explain:
[image]

Comment: Do `Explain`. Probably the query is not using an index.

Comment: There is no indices effective for shown query in tables structures.

Comment: @AllenKing Edited the question and attached the output of `Explain`. 
@Akina It shows that it's using the index.

Comment: This is where seems to be an issue.  `Using index condition `: where condition contains indexed and non-indexed column and the optimizer will first resolve the indexed column and will look for the rows in the table for the other condition (index push down)

Comment: The keylen also appears  too large.  Try adding `innodb_large_prefix = 1` in the conf file.

Comment: Note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate